# Can I create Singleton per application in PHP (php-fpm)?

Tags: php, thread-safety, singleton, fpm

How can I implement singleton per application? 
I woulde like to store single instance of class in memory and use (change) it in all requests in thread-safe mode.

Comment: 403 reputation and still don't know how to ask a question... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Twinfriends, sorry, but I don't understand you.

Comment: I'm tryting to tell you that your question is not following the rules of SO. Stackoverflow is here to help with specific programmimg questions. SO is NOT here to google for you / write code for you / give you advises. We want to see what you've tried so far, then we're going to help you. Or at least, we're going to try.

Comment: @Twinfriends, I can implement singleton per request. But I need singleton per app (for all request to my site). I found no solutions.

Comment: Are you even reading what I'm writing? Stackoverflow is NOT here to google for you. We're NOT going to write code for you. Try it by yourself, come back and post your code if it doesn't work. Then we'll help you. But NOBODY, really NOBODY is going to write the code for you.